# How do I use ionic 2 datepicker plugin with ion-input? Any other alternative?

Tags: angular, datepicker, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I am trying to use ionic native datepicker plugin. I am trying to use it with ion-input. upon click it should be able to select date and show the value in the input field. Unfortunately, when I use type ="date", it does pick and enter value from pop up calendar but at the same time it opens up two calendar. and If I change type to text or anything else, it pops up the calendar and doesn't allow me to select and enter value to field.

With time, I am not sure which type should I use?

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fS9a.png)
[In this you can see, when I click on input field, it opens light calendar behind the dark one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr1Pw.png)

Also, is there anything else other than ion-input which I can use as a form field?

Below is my code:

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Date</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="date" (input)="date = $event.target.value" [(ngModel)]="date" (click)="showCalendar()"></ion-datepicker>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Time</ion-label>
  <ion-input (input)="time = $event.target.value" [(ngModel)]="time" (click)="showTime()" ion-time-picker></ion-datepicker>
</ion-item>
```

home.ts

```js
showCalendar() {

  this.datePicker.show({
    date: new Date(),
    mode: 'date',
    titleText: 'set Date',
    androidTheme: this.datePicker.ANDROID_THEMES.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT
  }).then(
    date => console.log('Got date: ', date),
    err => console.log('Error occurred while getting date: ', err)
  );

}
showTime() {

  this.datePicker.show({
    date: new Date(),
    mode: 'time',
    androidTheme: this.datePicker.ANDROID_THEMES.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT
  }).then(
    date => console.log('Got date: ', date),
    err => console.log('Error occurred while getting date: ', err)
  );

}
```

Comment: you can try using `<input type="date"/> it, it also invoke native date picker and change css to match ion-input.

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa Thanks for ur answer. As you can see in html file, I am already using type="date" but unfortunately it invokes two calendar instead of one. How do I solve that?

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa Thanks for ur answer. As you can see in html file, I am already using type="date" but unfortunately it invokes two calendar instead of one. How do I solve that?

Comment: I was asking to try `<input type="date"/>` not `<ion-input type="date">`.

Comment: remove this- `(click)="showCalendar()"`

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa I tried removing click event; it worked. Does this mean I am not calling cordova datepicker native plugin? or its being called by type="date" ?

Comment: Yes, if it is ok for you then you don't need  cordova datepicker native plugin?

Comment: Let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa yeah it solved problem. I wanted to use datepicker plugin so that I can use different android themes. Also, this worked but I am still wondering how to use datepicker plugin in forms as an input field or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the final html code looks like below. Might be helpful to others:

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Date</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="date" (input)="date = $event.target.value"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Time</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="time" (input)="time = $event.target.value"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```